# What is the "/ios/index/DataStore" Folder for in React Native Development

Tags: ios, xcode, git, react-native

I am basically wondering if I should exclude the `/ios/index/DataStore` Folder within my `react-native init` Project from version control.

The default `.gitignore` file doesn't exclude it but it seems that the contents of this folder change with each build and can easily be regenared by running `react-native run-ios`.

Couldn't find any information what this folder is actually for.

Comment: hello i have same problem at my project. still no solution. looking forward to get answer from somebody

Comment: @swift2geek I have excluded it for now and haven't seen any downside to it

Comment: I try to exclude too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

xcodebuild indexes your project in order to speed up subsequent builds, you are safe to .gitignore this directory. If you'd like you change its location, that can be done via Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Advanced.

preferences window
[image]

Regarding a react-native project it's probably best to leave these settings alone as you are using the build scripts which are (as of react-native 0.53.0) hard-coded into react-native-cli.

Comment: I am using RN 0.61.5 how can I remove this from ios folder and move it to .gitignoree